# Raspberry pi 3 not booting, screen is blank

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, boot-issues

I recently purchased a raspberry Pi 3 and bought a 8 GB micro SD card with it I wrote the image file of Raspbian onto the micro-sd card with win32diskimager which took 2 hours and then attached my monitor to the Pi with HDMI cable, power supply was given by 5V and 2A through my samsung charger. The screen is blank. I tried using higher amp rated chargers but nothing seems to happen on the screen. On the board however both lights seem to turn on and the green light blinks with some pattern. Have I done anything wrong ? or have I skipped out any steps ?

Please Help,
Thanks

Comment: Certain the monitor and HDMI cable work?

Comment: I prefer using Etcher to flash sd card. Can you pre-select correct input on monitor? Have you attached keyboard and mouse - some people report screen saver kicking in. What resolution is your screen?

Comment: The HDMI connection is `HDMI` to `HDMI`? If not and is `HDMI` to `VGA`, then the adopter is `active` or `passive`? If it is `passive` consider to buy an `active` one and test it again. The red led is always `on`? If it is not always `on` consider to buy a tested psu for raspberry pi. The green led blinks in same periods of time between `on` and `off`? If yes then the SD card maybe doesn't have any OS or it is not properly flashed.

Answer (score 1):

> the green light blinks with some pattern

This indicates the boot partition on the card was found but something was wrong with some piece of firm/software before the linux kernel could deploy.

Taken from [here](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern), and excluding things which should no longer apply:

- 3 flashes: `start.elf` missing.
- 4 flashes: `start.elf` failed.
- 7 flashes: Kernel image not found.

Since this is a fresh image, the long and the short of it is basically you did not write it correctly to the card.  Since the first (boot) parition is VFAT, you should be able to look at it in any computer.  If not, this is another clue that the card is messed up.